# GridGain: Correct way to remove keys from a list

Tags: c#, .net, gridgain

I am using the Append/Prepend functionality of the GridGain .Net client, is this the correct approach? And what's the recommended way of removing items from this list?

```
IGridClientData cache = client.Data("partitioned_tx");

cache.Put<string, long[]>("testlist", new long[] { 1L});
cache.Append<string, long[]>("testlist", new long[] { 2L});
cache.Prepend<string, long[]>("testlist", new long[] { 0L});

var testlist = cache.GetItem<string, System.Collections.ArrayList>("testlist");
long[] array = (long[])test.ToArray(typeof(long));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with GridGain 6.2.0-rc2 you can store Lists of Portable Objects in cache directly without having to convert them to arrays.

Some more information on Portable Objects is provided here: [GridGain + .NET Client Connection Warnings / Dropouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408769/gridgain-net-client-connection-warnings-dropouts)

Comment: Thank @dmitriy I somehow missed this answer previously!